# Is there a way to get Guice to fail fast during Guice.createInjector

Tags: java, inversion-of-control, ioc-container, guice

My project is using [Guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/) as the IOC container responsible for providing dependencies (service classes) to a large graph of objects (mostly singletons). Sometimes if a dependency fails during construction and this dependency is required by many objects, the failure will occur over and over again adding the exceptions to the Guice `ProvisionException`.

I can understand the rational for this behaviour as it gives a list of all the errors that occur to save fixing issues piece meal. However, I would like to disable this feature and 'Fail Fast', as the repeated failure in this case is resource intensive. Further more the 'ProvisionException' contains a list of the same exception.

I do appreciate that this behaviour is symptomatic (smells) of bad practice in the implementation (i.e. resource intensive object creation), but since the dependencies are abstractions for which anyone can provide implementations and plugin using dependency injection there is little defence against it.

What I would like to know is:-

**Is there a parameter that enables Guice to exit Injector creation at the first exception?**

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:

```
@Test
    public void guiceExample()
    {
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new TestModule());
        try{
        IAmANeedyObject instance = injector.getInstance(IAmANeedyObject.class);
        }
        catch (ProvisionException e)
        {
            assertThat(e.getErrorMessages().size(),Is.is(2));
        }
    }
```

This test assets two exceptions have been thrown

```
import com.google.inject.AbstractModule;
import com.google.inject.Inject;

public class TestModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(IWasDesignedWithHonestIntent.class).to(NastyThrowingExample.class);
        bind(IMindMyOwnBusiness.class).to(SomeLucklessObject.class);
        bind(IAlsoMindMyOwnBusiness.class).to(SomeEquallyLucklessObject.class);
        bind(IAmANeedyObject.class).to(LowSelfEsteem.class);
    }
}

interface IWasDesignedWithHonestIntent {}

interface IMindMyOwnBusiness {}

interface IAlsoMindMyOwnBusiness {}

interface IAmANeedyObject {}

@Singleton
class NastyThrowingExample implements IWasDesignedWithHonestIntent {
    @Inject
    public NastyThrowingExample() throws LongSlowAgonisingDeathException {
        throw new LongSlowAgonisingDeathException("I am dying");
    }
}

class LongSlowAgonisingDeathException extends Exception {
    @Inject
    public LongSlowAgonisingDeathException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}

class SomeLucklessObject implements IMindMyOwnBusiness {
    @Inject
    public SomeLucklessObject(IWasDesignedWithHonestIntent designedWithHonestIntent) {
    }
}

class SomeEquallyLucklessObject implements IAlsoMindMyOwnBusiness {
    @Inject
    public SomeEquallyLucklessObject(IWasDesignedWithHonestIntent designedWithHonestIntent) {
    }
}

class LowSelfEsteem implements IAmANeedyObject {
    @Inject
    public LowSelfEsteem(IMindMyOwnBusiness iMindMyOwnBusiness, IAlsoMindMyOwnBusiness alsoMindMyOwnBusiness) {
    }
}
```

Comment: can you add your concrete example? I just tried to analyse it and always just get the first provisioning error that occurs, not a list of all possible errors ...

Comment: I will add a simple example later. However, note the `ProvisionException` is a wrapper exception for a collection of Exceptions that are thrown during the bootstrapping process. So you will only get one `ProvisionException` it will contain the same real Exception over and over.

Comment: I am aware that making this edit `bind(IWasDesignedWithHonestIntent.class).to(NastyThrowingExample.class).asEagerSingleton();` to the example above it only throws one exception. But my question is whether Guice has an option to fail fast to avoid putting `.asEagerSingleton()` on each bind that may fail, or if I don't want singleton objects.

Comment: @user:290425 I have posted an example now

Comment: Try throwing an Error instead of an Exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a parameter that enables Guice to exit Injector creation at the first exception?

I'm afraid that don't, it doesn't.

You will have to continue with a code like your example.
You can always suggest this for the Guice team on their Google Code page.